# Is it possible to inspect DOM modifications as they happen?

Tags: html, debugging, browser, mouseevent

I'm trying to look at the html produced by a jQuery tooltip plugin (qTip v1).  The tooltip only appears when I hover over the element with my mouse pointer.  Normally I'd just inspect the html or dig deeper with Chrome's developer console, but as soon as I do that the tooltip disappears because the mouseover event ends.  The tooltip's position is outside the normal flow of the document so I can't set up the Elements tab (Chrome) easily to view it as it's happening.  Is there a method in any browser that freezes the DOM with a hotkey for inspection purposes? I'm open to other ideas as well--anything that lets me inspect an element that my mouse is not necessarily near that will disappear when my mouse moves. I don't want to start messing with putting debugger's in the plugin's javascript.

Comment: I'd really like to see the outcome of this. In the past I've been doing this by pressing CTRL-A to select the entire page, then pasting it into an HTML-aware editor such as *ahem* Dreamweaver. Not exactly ideal, but it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**DOM Breakpoints**

DOM breakpoints in Chrome may do the trick: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/scripts-breakpoints#dom

You just need access to a parent element where the tooltip will be appended.  You can then stop all Javascript which will prevent any Javascript removing anything from the DOM.

**Addendum from question author:**

You can also "break on attribute modification", this pauses the Javascript execution when an attribute is modified on subtree elements.  This option is under the same menu same menu as subtree modification.

Comment: +1 That's pretty neat and might be quite useful.  Thanks for sharing it.  The only issue is I don't know what element to use.  I tried the body element and nothing happened.  I think that since it's position:absolute, there's no parent element that I can choose which will work.

Comment: All elements will have a parent element except for `html`, that's the nature of XML, it may be that the subtree modification must be a direct child.

Comment: Yeah... unfortunately if the parent isn't body or html, I have no idea where the silly plugin is putting them.

Comment: Is it a browser plugin or a framework plugin, for example, a jQuery plugin?

Comment: And you can't see it in the DOM? I just looked at qTip v1 and I can promise you it's there.  It doesn't remove it from the DOM after a mouseout event.  Instead it hides it.  To find it: simply bring the tooltip up in the interface, go to developer console in chrome and execute `document.querySelectorAll(".qtip");`.  It should give you a list of all qTip tooltips in the DOM.

Comment: I can find it in the DOM, but no matter where I put break on subtree modification I can't get it to break one a qtip hover-over.  I'm not sure the subtree is actually being modified in a way that's detectable by this listener.

Comment: Aha, finally worked.  Used break on attribute modification instead of break on subree modification.  I think this is the closest we're gonna get.  Thanks for the help.