# Chrome Web Developer: How to find which script has interacted with a specific DOM element

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

Often, when a script has interacted with my DOM (added classes for example, or changed inline CSS) I have to just search my html to see where it is..

Is there some smart way to use Dev Tools into revealing me / taking me to the script in question?

Comment: As far as I know, once a script has done something, it is impossible to tackle it down. You would have to use *break points*. But I might be wrong.

Comment: yep DOM Breakpoints will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14219636/is-it-possible-to-inspect-dom-modifications-as-they-happen